# How to convert protobuf ListValue into python List?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, mypy, idl

I have a protobuf ListValue which I would like to convert into a Python List. However, I believe I have a conceptual misunderstanding as the following attempts have failed

```
my_list_value: ListValue = ...
my_list = list(my_list_value)
```

and mypy complains:

```
error: No overload variant of "list" matches argument type "ListValue"
```

Similarly, I tried:

```
prob_output_list: List[float] = []
for elt in my_list_value:
  prob_output_list.append(elt)
```

yet also receive

```
error: "ListValue" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How can we explicitly force a cast without triggering mypy? Would it be just via #pragma ignore

Comment: I'd really advice to stop jumping through hoops and switch to [`betterproto`](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/python-betterproto/) instead, it works with native python types.

Comment: Sadly it's not really my decision whether to use protobuf or not...

Comment: Also you have an option to use stub files along actual definitions (generated with [mypy-protobuf](https://github.com/nipunn1313/mypy-protobuf)) to satisfy `mypy`. `betterproto` **is** protobuf - just more pythonic implementation of the protocol, binary compatible. And it's weird that `ListValue` doesn't have `__iter__` in stubs - [it should](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#listvalue).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I believe this PR actually attempts to fix the annotation issues: https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/9323